# FontAwesome not working

Tags: font-awesome

I'm trying to get [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to work on my site without Bootstrap. I've downloaded the font files and the CSS files bundled with them, and have changed the CSS file so that it points to the fonts on my server.

In the web inspectors of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, I get no missing resource errors, and the links to both the CSS file and the fonts aren't broken.

The HTML I'm trying is

```
<i class="icon-cheveron-right"></i>Next
```

"Next" appears fine, but without so much as a blank space or offset for the icon. I've checked and double-checked the instructions on the FontAwesome site, but can't get the icons to display at all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me. your code has an extra 'e' in chevron

```
<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Next
```